# Performance Counter maximum during interval?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I have an application that is executing a number of operations.  I have some performance counters that measure the average time it takes to execute the operation between intervals.  I would like a counter that for each interval will display the maximum time that it took to handle one of the operations since the last interval.

For an average I use a PerformanceCounter of type AverageTimer32 instance and an AverageBase instance.  What kind of performance counter would I use for tracking the maximum operation time between intervals?  How would it be incremented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such counter type. Trying to implement your own (read current value, compare, change if is a new max) is flawed under concurency conditions as there is no atomic interlockedcompareexchange API for performance counter.

Comment: Does that mean implementing something like this is not possible?

Comment: You can use an variable that tracks the max value and is incremented under appropiate locking, and publish it as an ordinary absolute counter.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that is really an option.  You can't tell when the last interval is taken so you can't keep track of the max since the last interval.

Comment: You keep track of max since the application start up time. Or you keep a series in the application and manage it your self and publish a counter as 'max in the last 60 seconds' for example. A max between the intervals *for each reader* is impossible, it means the perf counters need to keep track of readers, which is not how counters work, all they have is *one* single raw value, the rest is computed by the readers